# jQuery ajax, how to call again from response text

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to use ajax like below;

**jquery code:**

```
$("a.generate").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        data: {tag: $(this).html()},
        success: function(data){
            $("#terms div.content").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**the link I call from:**

```
<a href="#" class="generate"> tag </a>
```

**after call, ajax loads the links that I can call again like below:**

```
<a href="#" class="generate"> term </a>
<a href="#" class="generate"> term2 </a>
```

The problem is, if I click the links from ajax loaded data, ajax doesn't load anymore.

**edit:**

After I edited the code with the on() method like below, the code does nothing:

```
$("body").on('click', 'a.generate', function(){
    $.ajax({
        data: {tag: $(this).html()},
        success: function(data){
            $("#terms div.content").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**solved:**

the jquery version, I have added in head tags were 1.6.2, I have updated the version, no problem now. thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `on` to add your event handlers.

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(){
});
```

This will wire up every single anchor that's ever clicked.  To be more selective, just pass in a selector for the second parameter

```
$(document).on("click", "a.someClass", function(){
});
```

Note that `live`—a common suggestion for events in jQuery—is **deprecated**; `on` is the preferred way to add events that will also work with dynamically added content.

Also, since `on` was added in jQuery 1.7, if you're using an older version, you'll have to use `delegate`.  Note that the order of the selecter and event are reversed:

```
$(document).delegate("a.someClass", "click", function(){
});
```

Here are the [docs for on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I doubt the OP wants to hook this to every single link in the whole document.  `$(document).on("click", ".generate", function(){});` would make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Use the live() event handler: http://api.jquery.com/live/

edit: Use on http://api.jquery.com/on/ instead like Adam said, my first link has been deprecated.